# How to benefit from Spring/JPA for executing parametrized queries without referring to an entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Basically I am looking for a nice mechanism to do something like

```
@Query(value ="generateReport", nativeQuery = true)
public void generateCSVReport(Path filename, UUID managerUuid);
```

where generateReport is a parametrized query located in `@EnableJpaRepositories(namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:/foo/bar/file.sql)`
that includes a

```
COPY ( SELECT * FROM foo) TO file WITH (FORMAT CSV)
```

Without the need of defining a Repository. Indeed I tried `JpaRepository<Void,Void>` but it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any entity attached to your repository then you don't really need to be implementing JpaRepository.. or even CrudRepository since it doesn't make sense for you to have any CRUD operations without an entity.

Try implementing the base interface `Repository<T, ID extends Serializable>` instead.

Also `Repository<Void, Void>` wont work since `Void` does not extend `Serializable` and also because Void is not a managed type (i.e. it is not an @Entity).

Using Spring Data repositories to do this you would have to create an empty dummy entity just to pass in. It would probably make sense to map this to the foo table you are querying in your SQL:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class DummyEntity extends Serializable {

  //Blank
}
```

Then extend `Repository<DummyEntity, Integer>`. This probably indicates that Spring Data repos aren't the best solution for this problem though.

Comment: It returns me Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class java.lang.Object

Comment: Ohh yes I hadn't thought about that. I'll update my answer.